# HIbernate doesn't see a column

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I've got the following table in a PostgreSQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
age INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_name_uindex ON users (name);
```

And the following Hibernate entity mapping:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    private int id;

    @Column (name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column (name = "age")
    private int age;

    public User() {}
    // setters and getters
}
```

And a function to get all users from table

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public List<User> getAll() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> fromUser = cq.from(User.class);
        cq.select(fromUser);
        TypedQuery<User> tq = em.createQuery(cq);

        return tq.getResultList();
    }
}
```

When I run this function, the following SQL gets run (outputted using show_sql):

```
select
    user0_.id as id1_,
    user0_.age as age1_,
    user0_.name as name1_ 
from
    User user0_
```

And the following error occurs:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: column user0_.id not exists
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you able to run the query in any DB administration tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the actual query against your database:

```
select user0_.id as id1_,
       user0_.age as age1_,
       user0_.name as name1_
  from User user0_
```

It looks to me like your Hibernate query is trying to select from the `User` table, when your table is named `users`.

You can resolve this by adding the following annotation to your entity:

```
@Table(name = "USERS")
```